# how modify modal window in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i write aplication in bootstrap and i must do button witch open table in new window. I use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but is one problem - it show me new window with bar for page address. But in my aplication i must have only window with table, without address bar or something else. is possible to do this? it must looks like modal dialog but open in new window. probably it is very stupid but i can't see tutorial/example how delete address bar.

Comment: Where are you using bootstrap modal ?

Comment: I have to agree with the answer that a modal is much better in terms of UX, but if you really must do this in a separate [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) can accept an optional parameter listing the features (size, position, scrollbars, etc.) of the new window as a string.

Comment: window.open don't looks like I want. as i write - i must hide address bar in new window, and i ask you how do this.

Answer (score 0):

i don't see why you need to use window.open if you have bootstrap modals...

just use

```
$(".your_modal").modal()
```

check this:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: is not my idea, i rather modal in bootstrap but boss want to open in new dialog window.